# Cannot catch good timing for executing function which fill array in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I am working on some modal, there is "Rule" section.
You can set there which rules you want.

That looks like this:
[image]

Also there is that "Add Rule" button, on which you click and get the new "Rule to set up".

This is result of by clicking on "Add Rule" button:
[image]

Now you have that "rules operators"  which are buttons: "OR", "AND" and "EXCLUDE": 
[image]

Based on That which "button" you choose there are in the rules dropdown options will be different/changed.

That is reason why I need for every rule one "copy" of array for that dropdown.

Cus if you choose in Rule 2 -> "OR" operator in dropdown will be different options. 
Problem is cus that array is in the same memory and that changed is made also in dropdown of Rule 1.

To avoid that, I want to make that every Rule have his own copy of array.

That Rule section is made by for loop, and every time when you click "Add Rule" that rules.array will be increase for one, and there we will "new rule rendered".

"rules" array have initial value of 1. When you click "Add Rule" there will be 2.

I use that array to loop through her and for each iteration I make new "index which is array". That means if we have 2 rules, we will have one array with two index(arrays).

**Main problem is in Typescript:** in updateAudienceRulesList() function, cus this this.audienceDto.rules.length is empty when you click "New Rule". On the start that array have value 1, cus by default you have one rule.

```
@Input() audienceDto: AudienceDtoData;
@Input() parentForm: NgForm;

public ruleOperatorArray = RULE_OPERATOR_ARRAY;
public audienceRulesTypesList = [];

constructor() {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.updateAudienceRulesList();
}

updateAudienceRulesList() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.audienceDto.rules.length; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        this.audienceRulesTypesList[i] = RULE_ARRAY;
    }
}

onSelectRuleOperator(ruleOperator, value, i) {
    ruleOperator = value;
    this.audienceRulesTypesList[i] = ruleOperator === 'OR' ? RULE_ARRAY_WITHOUT_GEO_RULES : RULE_ARRAY;
}
```

Here is HTML of rules.component:

```
<div *ngFor="let rule of audienceDto.rules; let i = index"
 class="nano-f-r nano-rule-wrapper">
<hr>
<div class="nano-label">
    <span class="nano-m-05">
        Rule {{ i + 1 }}
    </span>
</div>
<div class="nano-f-c nano-f">

    <div *ngIf="i > 0"
         class="nano-f-r nano-f-30" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
        <label *ngFor="let ruleOperator of ruleOperatorArray"
               [class.active]="rule.ruleOperator === ruleOperator.value"
               (click)="rule.ruleOperator = ruleOperator.value"
               (click)="onSelectRuleOperator(rule.ruleOperator, ruleOperator.value, i)"
               class="nano-radio-button">
            <span>
                {{ ruleOperator.name }}
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="nano-f-r nano-f-30">
        <nano-drop-down [arrayOfOptions]="audienceRulesTypesList[i]"
                        [selectedOptions]="rule.ruleClass"
                        (selectedOptionsChange)="rule.onRuleChange($event)">
        </nano-drop-down>
        <div (click)="audienceDto.removeRule(i)"
             class="nano-f-r nano-f-30 nano-bc-ws hover-effect nano-c-p nano-ml-2">
            <i class="fa fa-times nano-m-a"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Keep one version of the options array, but clone it and use the clone to fill up the html options so the options don't change, only which options are shown where.

Comment: @Shilly tnx for rply, Ok I will try on that way.